# Send picked images as result of Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I've made a gallery, it can be chosen to select some images.

For example when an app needs to load a pic you may want to use my gallery. So I receive the intent in Activity A (List of folders) the user enters Activity B (List of the selected folder's images) and chooses the images he wants to load in the other app. The only problem is that I don't know how to pass the images back to the other app, I've tried with setResult() but it doesn't work.

I suspect the problem is because I return the images from a different activity (Activity B) rather than the main activity (Activity A).
Does anyone know what should I do? Do you need to see my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use the default gallery app? If so, I know how to solve your problem.

Comment: @AkashBhave What do you mean? My app is a gallery.